# Getting wrong output in any math operation

Tags: c++, math, codeblocks

#include 
    #include

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x  ;
    int y ;
    int sum ;
    sum = x-y ;
    cout << "Enter your first number here: ";
    cin >> x ;
    cout << "Enter your second one : ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "your result is " << sum << endl;
    system("pause") ;
}
```

Now when i  run this program:

```
Enter your first number here: 88
Enter your second one : 22
your result is 2221280 .
```

i've searched a lot but don't know what to do .

Comment: You ask for the input after you calculated your result. `sum = x-y ;` is executed before `cout<<"Enter your first number here: " ;` Note: that c++ is executed in order an assignment is not a mathematical relationship that gets reevaluated every time you print sum.

Comment: ***i've searched a lot but don't know what to do .*** Move `sum = x-y ;` down to after you get the value of  `x` and `y` and before you print `sum`. the order of the statements is important.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks the problem is solved now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ arithmetic on builtin types isn't symbolic (like `syms` library in MATLAB if you're familiar with that). It's numeric. `sum = x - y` doesn't establish a relationship that causes `sum` to be updated whenever `x` or `y` are updated. It takes the value of `x` and `y` at that moment, executes the operation, and assigns it to `sum`. The relationship between `sum`, `x`, and `y` is ended after this transaction.

As an aside this should be called `difference` not `sum`, since you're subtracting.

Comment: You can do the syms thing in C++ also https://godbolt.org/z/A_sKMA